# I am using the same public key to encrypt string, in android and xcode but the code has diferences

Tags: android, xcode, character-encoding

With Xcode

```
"D«p.ú%ó*–µ&1£e†’»Œ™+}¹f-ð#BûzJyìñµL5‹"å#è£Í˜9@Q˜Æ­Ú•jÉ œÇºýNŠ­É¹7@üä_³šÚˆæÛÍ£É…Öë‰ÿÈ¢
```

With Android

```
 "D«p.ú%ó*µ&1£e»+}¹f-ð#BûzJyìñµL5"å#è£Í9@QÆ­ÚjÉ ÇºýN­É¹7@üä_³ÚæÛÍ£ÉÖëÿÈ¢
```

There are little difference into files content. why? charset??

Android Code:

final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

```
         // Se encripta el identificador usando la clave pública
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
         textoEncriptado = cipher.doFinal("prueba12341375703787505".getBytes());
         System.out.println(new String(textoEncriptado,"ISO-8859-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a problem like this. Android has different process of converting types. So I believe it is up to Android.

Comment: ¿Converting types?, where¿?
 final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
       
    // Se encripta el identificador usando la clave pública
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    textoEncriptado = cipher.doFinal("prueba12341375703787505".getBytes());
    System.out.println(new String(textoEncriptado,"ISO-8859-1"));